# Android - Custom back button (back stack)

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments, android

I have implemented my own back stack but I'm not sure what is wrong or what I could improve, my scenario: I have a project with 2 activities, the first one is the "SplashActivity" - where I load some network data - the second one, the MainActivity.

Inside of my MainActivity I have a fragment and inside of this fragment a webview.

The back button should behave like:

- When the user doesn't navigate inside of my webview, close the app.
- When the user navigates in webview, use the back history of the browswer.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

    Log.d("lastfragment", String.valueOf(fragmentStack.lastElement().getId()));

    if (fragmentStack.size() >= 2) {

        // implement normal behavior?

        Fragment activeFragment=fragmentStack.lastElement();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        activeFragment.onPause();
        ft.remove(fragmentStack.pop());

        Fragment returnToFragment=fragmentStack.lastElement();
        String name = returnToFragment.getClass().getName();
        if(name=="SplashScreen" || name=="LoginFragment"){

            // close?

        }
        else {

            // implement normal behavior?

            returnToFragment.onResume();
            ft.show(returnToFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
    else {
        //close ??

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code i hope solved this your problem.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN, YOUR_FRAGMENT_OBJECT);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); // Your fragment add to back stack
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, what exactly do you mean with "YOUR FRAGMENT OBJECT" ?

Comment: Fragment fragmentObject = new Fragment();

First time calling your fragmentObject pass to that replace method and after then handle on back button which is add to back stack ok now got it.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand, can you edit your answer with your code and mine ? thanks

Comment: Your onBackPressed method code should be wrong i think and please rewise and rewrite code. Above four lines code should handle fragments.